# Notepad ++ : Selecting and converting an entiere column into a string

Tags: replace, notepad++, sql-insert

I am trying to build a `INSERT` MS SQL query in Notepad++

I seek help from the community on how to carry out the following tasks:

- Select an entire column in Notepad++ (there are multiple columns) and convert that selection to a string
  For eg. I have a column with these values (2020-9-21) I want to select and convert the entiere column to a string..end result should be `'2020-9-21'`
- Add `(` and `),` at the start and end of each line

**E.g. of the data**

```
2166    0   2020-09-21      JPP 172432  10.70   0   2021110 123403948123    938 0000002930BC3040303 SALE    1
```

**Desired output**

```sql
(2166,0,'2020-09-21','JPP',172432,10.70,0,2021110,123403948123,938,'0000002930BC3040303','SALE',1),
```

Comment: Which is your column separator?

Comment: @horcrux: Looks tab-delimited.

Comment: @BoltClock Selecting the text, to me it doesn't

Comment: @horcrux: Rendered code blocks convert tabs to spaces. You'd have to click edit and select the text within the editor. You'll find tabs there. On the surface you'll notice that the values always start in 4-character intervals, which will clue you in that it may be tab-delimited.

Comment: @horcrux - The rendered output isn't tabbed but it is tab delimited. You can see if you edit the post.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace with regex:

```
^(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)$
```

To:

```
($1,$1,'$3','$4',$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,'$11','$12',$13),
```

Answer (score 1):

Select "Regular expression" as "Search Mode". Then:

- Find: `(?m)^((?:[^\t]*\t){N})([^\t]*)`
- Replace: `$1'$2'`

Where `N` is the field that you want to turn into a string (starting from 0).

Regex explanation:

- `(?m)` is the [multi-line flag](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).
- `^` matches the beginning of the row (or of the string, if you are not in multi-line mode).
- `[^\t]` matches a non-tab characther.
- `*` is the [zero-or-more operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).
- `(...)` is a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), i.e. a group that can be referenced in the replacement.
- `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group.

In order to obtain your expected result, in a second moment you can replace all the `\t` with `,`, all the beginning of rows (i.e. `(?m)^`) with `(` and all the endings of rows (i.e. `(?m)$`) with `),`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to go, you have to add manually parenthesis at the beginning and at the end:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b(?:([\d.]+)|(\S+))\h+`
- Replace with: `(?1$1)(?2'$2'),`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              # word boundary
(?:             # non capture group
    ([\d.]+)        # group 1, 1 or more digit or dot
  |               # OR
    (\S+)           # group 2, 1 or more non space
)               # end group
\h+             # 1 or more horizontal space
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1             # if group 1 exists (i.e. only digits and dot)
    $1              # put group 1 without any changes
)               # endif
(?2             # if group 2 exists (i.e. string values)
    '$2'            # put group 2 surrounded with quotes
)               # endif
,               # comma
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]